# How to upload a iOS build to the App Store with an account which is set to App Manager role in my client's iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I need to upload an iOS App for my client.
I was able to archive the program using a distribution provisioning profile which was created by the client.
But I can't upload the archive to the store.

When I click "Upload to App Store" button on the Xcode organizer,
Xcode says "To submit to the iOS App Store, select a Development Team to use for provisioning:".

But the pulldown doesn't contain a development team, but contains only my apple id which is set to App Manager role of the client's account.
My apple id (mail address) is shown in the pulldown but it can not be selected.

In the account preference of Xcode, my apple id's role is displayed as "Free" and the team name is "my name (Personal Team).
But I guess the role should be shown as "App Manager" and team name should be my client name.
And no provisioning files are shown in my account's details window in the preference.

My client's developer program is a normal developer program, not enterprise version.

Does anyone know how to upload an archive to the app store using App Manager account?

Comment: This question isn't really fit for StackOverflow because it's not exactly about programming, but since it's already here; you also need to be a member of their developer team (https://developer.apple.com/account/), which is separate from iTC.

Comment: @FilipRadelic I think there is no member management feature for individual version of developer program. Probably it is only available with enterprise version of developer program. Can't I upload a binary with App Manager role of individual developer program?

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan iTunes Connect's documentations says App Manager role also can upload binary. Do I really need Admin role? Aren't there other reasons why I can't upload the archive?

Comment: I think you need their team certificate. Ask them to send you their team certificate.

Comment: @BrettDonald Do you know if it is possible with individual developer program or it is possible only with app developer enterprise program?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. An Enterprise developer membership is all about distributing apps within an organisation without using the app store. But if you're trying to publish an app on their behalf, you'll need their team certificate.

Comment: @BrettDonald Do you know how to create a team certificate with individual developer program account? In the developer center, only Development or Production certificate can be created. There is no option to create a team certificate. I wasn't able to find any documentation or articles about creating a team certificate.

Comment: The team certificates are not in developer center. We copy them from one developer's Mac to another. Use the Keychain Access app on another developer's Mac to find the cert and export both the cert and the private key associated with it. Then copy the file to your Mac and import it.

Comment: When you say that your client's developer program is "normal" rather than "enterprise", the correct term is an "organization" membership. There are three types of membership, "individual", "organization", and "enterprise". All my comments are based on the assumption that your client has an "organization" membership, and that they are wanting to include you in their team so that you can publish apps as that organization. Here is a summary of the different membership types: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: If you have your own individual membership as well, then you should have two apple ids, one for your individual membership, and then another apple id to attach to your client's membership.

Comment: @BrettDonald I didn't know there are 3 types of the programs. My client's program is probably "individual". Do my client have to change his program to "organization" to make it possible for me to upload binary for him?  I have my own individual developer program account as well and I already created another my apple id for client.

Comment: So if its an individual membership then it could only have one Apple ID associated with it ... and presumably that would be your clients Apple ID. If your client is prepared to share his Apple ID and password with you, plus his individual certificate, then you could publish as him. But I wouldn’t recommend such an arrangement; an organisation membership would be better. I believe it is the same price.

Comment: @BrettDonald I'll check my client's membership type and if it is "individual", I'll ask him to upgrade it to "organization". I've spent almost half a day to find the solution for this issue. And I believe you solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it's individual account and you are just an iTC member, you can upload the binary via Application Loader. Xcode won't let you do it unless you are developer account member too.

Comment: I checked my client's account type. My client's account was "organization". And I was able to join the team. Thank you Brett and thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Please use Application Loader instead XCode
Open XCode choose XCode Menu -> Developer Tool
You needs convert .xcarchive to .ipa